# AWX Normal User with admin rights can't add job template

Tags: roles, ansible-awx

Good morning everyone,

I am having a problem with the roles and permissions of users and teams in AWX.
I feel like there are many ways to do the same thing and I get a little confused.

To explain my problem, I created a new normal user. I assigned him all possible rights (I think) but the user still does not have the possibility to add a job template.

What is the right way to add rights to a team, then to a specific user please?
How can I activate the "add job template" option?

Thank you so much,

**AWX version**
17.0.1

**Installation method**
docker on linux

**Modifications**
no

**Ansible version**
2.9.17

**Operating system**
Redhat 8.3

**Web browser**
Chrome

**Steps to reproduce**

Assign a user to a team:

- Go to Teams > Select the team
- Go to Access tab
- Click on Add
- Select Users
- Select the User
- Select: Admin, read, and member roles

Assign roles to a team:

- Go to Teams > Select the team
- Go to Access tab.
- Click on Add
- Select Teams
- Select the team
- Select: Admin, read, and member roles

**Expected results**
The expected result is a user with admin, member and read rights associated to a team with admin, member and read rights.
The user should be able to add a job template.

**Actual results**
The user is not able to add a job template.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I needed to sync AWX with git first. Its working now.
Closing the case.

Thanks